# If someone changes their number and you never stopped sharing your location, would the new person with that number see your location?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, find-my-friends

I have shared my location with someone and it might be possible that he will change his number. If I don’t stop sharing my location with that associated phone number, will a new person with the number be able to see my location? Or is it still connected to the original person’s iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

That information is actually not passed through the network using the phone number as the identifier. It's run through iCloud and is tied to Apple ID. The new person with the same phone number won't see your location.

Answer (score 0):

My husband and myself changed our numbers and his old number was still associated with his apple id. So I had to go into his apple account and change that, but yep It was still sharing his location. Im assuming if someone else claimed that number then they would have to connect to their apple id and it would automatically disconnect that feature.